# ssh X forwarding web browser flash

Tags: ssh, x11

I have a question regarding ssh X forwarding. Specifically when it comes to forwarding X program i.e. some web browser client, for example Iceweasel.

X Server <--(request to display Iceweasel executed on X client)--- X client

And lets assume I would like to execute in this web browser some dynamic content like Flash or a Javascript game.

My question: Will it be executed on the X server or on the X client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 aspects that I always keep in mind to keep these things straight in my head.

1. There is software that needs to drive the display of graphics on my local computer. (i.e. talk to my video card and form shapes etc. on my monitor).
2. There is some usable application (such as a terminal or Iceweasel) that is running, which needs to display itself.

So with X everything is backwards. The server is you, and the clients (applications such as Iceweasel) are attempting to connect to your X server. So the only data that's flowing through the ssh forwarded tunnel is the data that is related to an X client talking to an X server. Anything pertaining to the X Client (Flash, Javascript, etc.) is still running on the X Client.

```
X Server                   X Client                    .-,(  ),-.     
 __  _                    (Iceweasel)               .-(          )-.  
[__]|=|  <------------     __  _       <--------   (    internet     )
/::/|_|       ssh         [__]|=|                   '-(          ).-' 
             tunnel       /::/|_|                       '-.( ).-'     

                    ^    .-----------.
                     \    X Client #2 
                      \   __  _     
                         [__X Client #3
                         /:: __  _     
                            [__]|=|    
                            /::/|_|
```

Answer (score 3):

So, this is a confusing issue because of the terminology.  An X server is the process that interfaces with your computer's video hardware and provides X clients the ability to display graphics via the X protocol.  So, when you are connected via SSH with X forwarding, the X client is on the remote server, and the X server is the process on your local computer.

In this case, since iceweasel is running on the remote server (running as an X client), flash is executed on the remote server, however it is talking to your X server on your local computer using the X protocol, over the SSH tunnel.

Comment: That clarifies @sim's answer, thank you @jsbillings!

Answer (score 2):

The X server only handles display and keyboard/mouse input. It won't execute arbitrary code (that's what ssh is for). So if you launch a web browser, the flash and javascript execute on that same machine. The browser window will display on whatever machine the X server is running on. With X forwarding, this typically means that the machine with the ssh server is running the code, and the ssh client is running the X server.

Answer (score 0):

The flash will also execute on the SSH server (which is the X client), not on the SSH client (which is the X server). SSH forwarding is only sending the "output", so basically what you see to the SSH client, but it's executed on the Server.

This also means that you won't need to have the browser or flash installed on the SSH client, installing on the SSH server is enough.